# how to cast jbyteArray to a structure?

Tags: java, c, casting, java-native-interface

I am using the JNI between Java and C code to pass a byte[] array from Java to C.  In C, the parameter is a jbyteArray, like follows:

```
jint Java_com_my_example_Class_getResult(jbyteArray ary, JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz);
```

Now, once I receive 'ary' as a jbyteArray, I would like to cast it to a structure, like this one:

```
struct st {
   int first;
   int second;
};
```

What is the best and safest way to do this?  Should I try to convert the jbyteArray to a char array and then cast as normal, or is there a safer JNI related method for doing this?

Comment: See http://mindprod.com/jgloss/jni.html ; has lots of examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

call `GetByteArrayElements` to get a pointer-to-byte, and case that to your struct.  Then don't forget to make the corresponding release call.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't cast the `jbyteArray` to anything! You must use `GetByteArrayElements()` to get the actual `jbyte*` pointer; *then* you can cast the pointer. Don't forget to ReleaseByteArrayElements when you're done.